# hardcoded to relative paths

Tags: c#, winforms, path, relative-path, hardcoded

I'm working on a project that on the click of a button a random image for a folder I specified will appear in a specific picturebox.

Here's what I have already:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
    {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random r = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(r.Next(3).ToString() + ".jpg");
    }
}
```

Now how can i add a relative path to this? My hardcoded path is c:/users/ben/documents/visualstudio/projects/projectnet/resources/pictures.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is C# .net winforms please add the tags

Comment: you're better off storing "base" urls in app.config and work from there using [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx). Add System.Configuration as a reference prior to use.

Comment: `for a folder I specified` : do you mean you specified it as the developer (once), or is it something the end-user will specify? If the users specify it, you'll generally not need to know the relative path (rephrase: I see no use case)

Comment: Yes, it is for use on another computer. Pictures is a folder I created inside the resource folder of my project. My pictures are stored in this folder and I want to recall them without hardcoding. Since that won't work if you open my project on another pc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your `button1_Click` handler:

```
string imageFileName = r.Next(3).ToString() + ".jpg";
string basePath = @"c:\users\ben\documents\visualstudio\projects\projectnet\resources\pictures";

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(basePath, imageFileName);
```

As mentioned in the comments to your question it is a good idea to read your base directory from an external source, i.e. app.config, if you intend to run your application on a computer other than your own.